# Combining two asynchronous calls using CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to put the results of two asynchronous calls into a map, and throw the exception only when an `IOExcetion` occurs. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to use `CompletableFuture`
:

```
   public Map<String, Object> action() throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        CompletableFuture<Void> voidCompletableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String s = action1();
                    map.put("key1", s);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new CompletionException(e);
                }
            }
        });
        CompletableFuture<Void> voidCompletableFuture2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Integer integer = action2();
                    map.put("key2", integer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new CompletionException(e);
                }
            }
        });
        try {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(voidCompletableFuture, voidCompletableFuture2).join();
        } catch (CompletionException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException) cause;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public String action1() throws IOException {
        return "a";
    }
    public Integer action2() throws IOException {
        return 2;
    }
```

Is there a more concise way?

Comment: To test your code you can `throw new IllegalArgumentException()` in `action1` and see what you get. Then `throw new IOException()` and again see what you get.

Comment: It all depends on your exact use case, but each `CompletableFuture` should return a specific type `<String>` and `<Integer>` respectively.  Once the `join` completes (success or failure) you should be looking back at each completable futures `get()` and handling the individual exception.  This way you have finer control over the `Map` and the specific request that caused the error.